# Push notification is not receiving on device

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, ios9

I am using push notification through PHP script. Code seems to be working fine, it does not give me any error. But notification does not receive me on my device.

Here is my code:

```
$passphrase = '123';
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
                       'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                       $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
                 'alert' => $message,
                 'sound' => 'default'
                 );
    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

try this php code:
but you have to change device token and passpharse as you had set. you can download php script from below link

http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip

i have run this php script it's works well..

Comment: here is full tutorial link:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: But device token should be different for different devices as I think. I pass the device token as parameter, and it is not working.

Comment: Moreover, when I run openssl verify cert.pem, it gives me an error unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: don't use downloaded cert.pem file, create your own cert.pem file and update php script with passphrase , message, and device token.

Comment: don't worry if notification not arrive at this time because it  may be sever problem. try after some time. hope it will work well because i have run successfully.

Comment: Yes, I am using my pem file which I created from ssl certificate but did not get any notification.

Comment: Unable to get local issuer certificate. If I add a line `stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');` in my code, then it gives me an "error failed loading cafile stream: `entrust_2048_ca.cer'"

Comment: i gave u a full tutorial link in first comment please check it.

Comment: I have checked that link and did not get any solutions

Comment: are you sure you have checked this link???    http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: step by step info is given for pushnotification project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91489/discussion-between-ketan-chauhan-and-nishi-bansal).

Comment: Thanks. But I have created my pem file again. Now it is working fine.